# Deploying on tomcat server through jenkins on local host

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to deploy a simple war on tomcat server from my local jenkins server.
I have updated the ../conf/tomcat-users.xml file , below is a snap of my configurations in the Jenkins file:
[Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yDOG.png)

I can not see any change/updates in the console.log for deployment on the tomcat server:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDtJN.png)

I have searched a lot for this but could not find any reason why this configuration is not working. I am running tomcat on 8080 and Jenkins war on 9090 both on my local system separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to specify the IP of server at Tomcat URL field, not http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Hi tuan ,
Thanks for your reply , I tried that as well but did not worked out for me  :(

Answer (score 0):

I think Tomcat URL under Post-build Actions should be set to http://localhost:8080/manager/text

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue with this was that , the pom was located on my local system under : D:\EclipseWorkspace\TestWebApp
and it was not able to gather the war built up from my local file system target path i.e:
 D:\EclipseWorkspace\TestWebApp\target\war

Hence when the jenkins server tries to run the war from path:
C:\Users\kapil.s.jenkins\jobs\MyFirstMavenProject\workspace
it was not able to find out the war.

So there are two possible solutions for this issue:
1. Use git to manage your workspace (*Recomended*).
2. A temporary fix : create a post build step in the jenkins configuration to copy the war(*Not Recomended*):
[Fix Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exczV.png)